# Finding exact eqality of two strings using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

In my C# app I need to search strings to find whether they are abbreviations of units of measure. For example, I need to find "mm", for millimeters, "l" for liters, "m2" for square meters, "kg" for kilograms and so on.
I need a match only if the string is exactly equal to the pattern, but not when the pattern is contained within a larger string. For example, if the string is equal to "mm", I want a match, but not when the string is, say, "the length is 55 mm".

I know that the simplest way would be to use a series of if - else if statements and the == operator, but may problem is that I don't know in advance the names of all the units the users will search for, and also, they could work with different sets of units. For example, one time it could be length and volume units (mm, m, cm, m3, l), and in some other case it could be electrical units (A, V, W, MW, kWh).

So, my idea is to add to the project a short XML file from witch the application will read at runtime the actual units and compose a regular expression to use for searching strings.
As a first try, I used this approach:

```
private bool IsUnit(String theString)
    {
        Regex regExUnits = new Regex("^(?i)m2|m3|kg|mm|cm|[mthl]$");
        Match m = regExUnits.Match(theString);
        return m.Success;
    }
```

but it dosen't work as I want. I get a match for "mm", but I also get a match for "the length is 55 mm"

I thought that if I use both "^" and "$" anchors, it would be interpreted as "match if the pattern is found at the beginning *AND* and the end of the string", which is true only in case of exact equality. But no, it seems that it is interpreted as "match if the pattern is found at the beginning *OR* and the end of the string".

I have already used regular expressions before, but in much simpler cases than this one, so, for the moment I am stuck.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: With ^ and $ you're not actually matching "beginning and end of the string", but your matching beginning and end of LINE.
You'll need \A and \Z for this. You're problably not searching multiline strings, but it's worth to note this.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this. I'd use a `HashSet<string>` - or even just a simple array, if there aren't many elements:

```
static readonly string[] Units = { "m2", "m3", "kg", "mm", "cm", 
                                   "m", "t", "h", "l" };

private static bool IsUnit(string text)
{
    return Units.Contains(text);
}
```

Or:

```
static readonly HashSet<string> Units = new HashSet<string> { 
    "m2", "m3", "kg", "mm", "cm", "m", "t", "h", "l" };

// IsUnit method as before
```

For simple string equality, regular expressions are more trouble than they're worth IMO.

Of course the units can be specified on a per-instance basis of the enclosing class, or whatever - I've only hard-coded them statically here as your question had them hard-coded too.

EDIT: To make this case insensitive, the simplest approach is probably to use the `HashSet` version and construct it with an appropriate [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hc8kytd.aspx), e.g.:

```
static readonly HashSet<string> Units =
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { ... };
```

(You'll need to work out *exactly* what kind of case-insensitivity you want though, in terms of culture sensitivity.)

Given that unit names *aren't* generally case-insensitive though, I'd advise against this.

Comment: You should convert `text` to lower case to make it case insensitive (as the expression was).

Comment: how do you do that so fast?

Comment: @SamIam, he first writes a 1 line answer, then fills it in the 5 min scope. ;-)

Comment: @Qtax about the `toLower`, units are case sensitive.   Mm is 1000,000 meters, and mm is .001 meters

Comment: @SamIam, I'm not saying that it's the proper way, just what the OP seems to want.

Comment: @Qtax: Using ToLower would be the wrong approach, IMO (mostly due to Turkey). Better to use a case-insensitive comparison. I've edited my answer to mention that, but also to keep the case-sensitive versions which I believe are more appropriate.

Comment: I think you should update the HashSet example. I can't imagine you would want to use the same IsUnit method as the array example, which won't take advantage of the HashSet behavior.

Comment: @Mark: Oops - I started writing the `Any` version to make the array method case-insensitive. It used to just be `Contains`, which is fine for both array and `HashSet`. Will fix.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - You are right, regular expressions are not the right tool in this case, but it's the only one I could think of for my problem. I tried this morning your idea of using the Any() method of a collection class, and it works perfectly for me. Thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the brackets!

```
"^(?i)(?:m2|m3|kg|mm|cm|[mthl])$"
```

The `?:` is optional and just means don't capture the value matched by this group.

Answer (score 0):

do you just need to know if it's some sort of unit?

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] sarr = { "kg", "li", "mm" };
    bool isUnit = sarr.Contains(input);
}
```

Comment: No, in this case I needed to know if the input string is exactly equal to one of the units from the set. This is part of a larger project of processing Excel sheets with technical data.